# Mithril: how to use multiple root elements?

Tags: mithril.js

When using `m.route`, does everything under it have to be rendered using Hyperscript (not counting JSX)? Is it possible to mix pure HTML with multiple separate parts rendered using Hyperscript?

Suppose I have this HTML code:

```html
<div id="root">
    <div class="header">
        <h3 id="header-text">Header Text</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="content"></div>
        <div id="sidebar"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to use Mithril to render multiple *parts* of the HTML sections? Like so (pseudo code):

```js
var root = document.getElementById('root');

var header = document.getElementById('header');
var content = document.getElementById('content');
var sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebar');
var footer = document.getElementById('footer');

var HeaderComponent = ...; // to render header text
var ContentComponent = ...; // main page content
var SidebarComponent = ...; // show links, bio, etc.
var Footer = ...; // contact info, etc.

var index = {
    view: function(){
        return [
            {el: header, component: HeaderComponent},
            {el: content, component: ContentComponent},
            {el: sidebar, component: SidebarComponent},
            {el: footer, component: FooterComponent}
        ];
    }
};

m.route(root, '/', {
    '/': index
});
```

so that *multiple separate parts* in the HTML code are rendered instead of just having a single root element? I really don't want to render the whole HTML skeleton template in Mithril as well, like this:

❌ DO NOT WANT:

```js
// I DON'T want this
m('div#root', [
    m('div.header', [
        m('h3#header-text', m(HeaderComponent))
    ]),
    
    m('div.container', [
        m('div#content', m(ContentComponent)),
        m('div#sidebar', m(SidebarComponent))
    ]),
    
    m('div#footer', m(FooterComponent))
]);
```

I know it's manageable, but I'd really like the base skeleton template to be inside the .HTML file, so that I can seamlessly wrap more HTML tags later on, like using Bootstrap classes (cards, container, rows, extra wrapping divs needed, etc.). Thanks :)!

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing stopping you from using the `m.mount` function several times, and several mount-points can be initialised this way:

```js
var count = 0 

m.mount(root1, {
  view: () => 
    m('button', {
      onclick: () => count++,
      textContent: 'Increase count',
    }),
})

m.mount(root2, {
  view: () =>
    m('p', 'Count: ', count)
})
```

```html
<h1>
  Static page with multiple roots
</h1>

<div id=root1>
</div>

<p>
  Intermediary static content
</p>

<div id=root2>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/mithril@2.0.4/mithril.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! I was researching this and came to the same conclusion. Thanks for taking your time and writing it out :)

Answer (score 1):

Using [@Barney](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64839835/3705191)'s answer below, I managed to solve this using a mix of `m.route` for the main content and multiple `m.mount`'s for the other components:

```js
var header = document.getElementById('header');
var content = document.getElementById('content');
var sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebar');
var footer = document.getElementById('footer');

var HeaderComponent = ...; // to render header text
var SidebarComponent = ...; // show links, bio, etc.
var Footer = ...; // contact info, etc.

// this will be shown under content
var HomePage = {
    view: function(){
        return m('p', [
            'Lorem ipusom dolor amit ',
            m(m.route.Link, {href: '/about'}, 'About')
        ]);
    }
};
var AboutPage = {
    view: function(){
        return m('p', 'This is the About page!');
    }
};

//// MAIN SOLUTION ////
var Layout = {
    // oninit is only run once
    oninit: function(){
        m.mount(header, HeaderComponent);
        m.mount(sidebar, SidebarComponent);
        m.mount(footer, FooterComponent);
    },
    
    // run on every route change:
    view: function(vnode){
        return m('div', vnode.children);
    }
};

m.route(content, '/', {
    // using RouteResolver
    '/': {
        render: function(){
            return m(Layout, m(HomePage));
        },
        onmatch: function(){
            // this will be called on route change, so update your mounted components as needed
            HeaderComponent.title = "Home Page";
        }
    },
    '/about': {
        render: function(){
            return m(Layout, m(AboutPage));
        },
        onmatch: function(){
            HeaderComponent.title = "About Page";
        }
    }
});
```

`m.route` is only used for `<div id="content">`, while all the other separate components (header, sidebar, footer) are instantiated using `m.mount`. I've wrapped the router with a Layout component that's used for all the routes, as this allows me to init and mount the separate components that will remain when routes change and not be affected by the main router. The router had to be modified to use [RouteResolver](https://mithril.js.org/route.html#routeresolver) to allow for more control and flexbility.

Notes:

- Only a *single* `m.route` allowed per application, but multiple `m.mount`'s allowed
- When the *same* component is assigned multiple routes (in this case, Layout), the subtree will NOT be deleted and rebuilt from ground up -- it will only be diffed and updated *[(source)](https://mithril.js.org/route.html#wrapping-a-layout-component)*. This way, we can use Layout component's `oninit` lifecycle hook to mount our other separate components, because oninit will only be called once.
- We must use a [RouteResolver](https://mithril.js.org/route.html#routeresolver) for the routes in `m.route`, which gives us more control over *how* the routes should be rendered and we also get hooks like `onmatch`, which fires BEFORE the route is initialized -- this is the perfect place to update our mounted components as needed!

Comment: Glad I could help! This pattern of using `m.route` and `m.mount` is extremely powerful. Inspiring to see Mithrils flexibility being used to find elegant solutions that map to a more holistic application model :)